# Optimized way to do an operation between a cell and an aggregated value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to add a new column which's the operation between a cell value and a groupped value by some other column.

Consider I have the following dataframe.

| Month | Apples Sold |
| --- | --- |
| October | 3 |
| October | 4 |
| October | 5 |
| November | 1 |
| November | 5 |

So in the example dataframe I want to do an operation between apple sold and the avg(apple_sold) **groupped by its month**. As an example let's say that **x=apple_sold** and **y=avg(apple_sold) in a month**, I want to do the operation (x-y)/y and name this column **variaton_month**:

| Month | Apple Sold | Variation_month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| October | 3 | -0.25 |
| October | 4 | 0 |
| October | 5 | 0.25 |
| November | 1 | -0.67 |
| November | 5 | 0.67 |

Now I know that this would be possible by groupping the dataframe then joining on month then doing the operation:

```
#Generating the example
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Month':['October','October','October','November','November'], 'Apples Sold':[3,4,5,1,5]})

#Doing the operation
df = pd.merge(df, df.groupby('Month').mean().reset_index(), on='Month', suffixes=('','_mean'))
df['Variation'] = (df['Apples Sold'] -  df['Apples Sold_mean'])/df['Apples Sold_mean']

# Cleaning the mess
df.drop('Apples Sold_mean', axis=1, inplace=True)
df
```

However if the dataframe's big this strategy can be very slow and unoptimized because of the *pd.merge* line. Is there a way to do these operations in a optimized way (maybe avoiding table join or using another library)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `groupby` + `transform` to broadcast the `mean` values per month, thereby avoiding the intermediate merge step

```
avg = df.groupby('Month')['Apples Sold'].transform('mean')
df['Variation_month'] = df['Apples Sold'].sub(avg).div(avg).round(2)
```

---

```
      Month  Apples Sold  Variation_month
0   October            3            -0.25
1   October            4             0.00
2   October            5             0.25
3  November            1            -0.67
4  November            5             0.67
```